# How to Validate a textfield in AEM/CQ so that no numbers are entered?

Tags: validation, textfield, aem

I have a requirement where in a textfield only alphabets from a-z or A-z be entered and nothing more. I am wondering how to do it. Are there any properties available. I couldn't find one. Can we use allowNumbers: false (its not working. I tried may properties but all in vain)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the property `regex` to specify a regular expression against which the value of the field would be tested.

For e.g., the following configuration would allow only alphabets and white spaces in the textfield. You can also use the `regexText` property to specify a custom error message when the validation fails.

```
<title jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" 
    fieldLabel="Text" 
    name="./text" 
    regex="/^[A-Za-z ]+$/"
    regexText="Kindly verify the field. Only characters are allowed." 
    xtype="textfield"/>
```

For more information, refer the [Widget API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.TextField)